# VueJS show information in modal based on clicked list entry's index

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, frontend

I am new to vueJS and not sure how to proceed.

I have an array of objects that contain a name and a job position. These objects are shown as a list with a button. When a user clicks the button, a modal pops up that displays the clicked persons name and their job.

How do I get the modal to display the correct info?

```
<div id="modal">
  <h2 class="membername">Name: {{ members[0].name }}</h2>
  <p class="memberposition">Position: {{ members[0].position}}</p>
</div>
```

The '[0]' in the vuejs brackets should be the index of whichever person the user clicked.

http://codepen.io/leetzorr/pen/QGJozR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `selectedMember` field and let it save the ID. Then base your modal on it and change only the `selectedMember`-field. I've updated your pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNrYvz